# Distinguish regions by clicking on cell borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, flood-fill

The code below has an issue identifying regions enclosed within a border.

If I surround all the "A" cells within a perimeter, it is identified as its own region; but if I enclose the "B" region first, it is not identified as its own region.

```js
const COLOR_PALETTE = ['#FDD', '#DFD', '#DDF', '#FFD', '#DBF', '#BFD', '#FDB', '#BDF'];
const CLICK_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 5;
const DATA = [
  ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
  ['C', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
  ['C', 'D', 'B', 'B'],
  ['C', 'D', 'D', 'D']
];

const $grid = $('#grid');

$grid.append($('<tbody>')
  .append(DATA.map((row, rowIndex) => $('<tr>')
    .append(row.map((val, colIndex) => $('<td>')
      .text(val).data('coords', [rowIndex, colIndex]))))));

$grid.on('click', 'td', onBorderClick);

function onBorderClick(event) {
    const $target = $(this);
  const rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  // Determine the closest border and toggle it
  if (x < CLICK_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD) {
    $target.toggleClass('selected-left');
    $target.prev().toggleClass('selected-right');
  } else if (x > rect.width - CLICK_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD) {
    $target.toggleClass('selected-right');
    $target.next().toggleClass('selected-left');
  } else if (y < CLICK_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD) {
    $target.toggleClass('selected-top');
    $target.parent().prev().children().eq($target.index()).toggleClass('selected-bottom');
  } else if (y > rect.height - CLICK_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD) {
    $target.toggleClass('selected-bottom');
    $target.parent().next().children().eq($target.index()).toggleClass('selected-top');
  }

  distinguishRegions();
}

function distinguishRegions() {
  // Clear previous regions
  $grid.find('td').css('background-color', '').removeData('region').removeAttr('data-region');
  let regionId = 0;
  $grid.find('td').each(function() {
    const $cell = $(this);
    if (!$cell.data('region')) {
      regionId++;
      floodFill($cell, regionId);
    }
  });
}

function floodFill($cell, regionId) {
  const queue = [$cell];
  while (queue.length > 0) {
    const $current = queue.shift();
    if ($current.length === 0 || $current.data('region')) continue;

    $current.data('region', regionId)
        .attr('data-region', regionId)
        .css('background-color', getRandomColor(regionId));

    const [r, c] = $current.data('coords');
    const neighbors = [
      !$current.hasClass('selected-top') && getCell(r - 1, c),
      !$current.hasClass('selected-bottom') && getCell(r + 1, c),
      !$current.hasClass('selected-left') && getCell(r, c - 1),
      !$current.hasClass('selected-right') && getCell(r, c + 1),
    ];

    queue.push(...neighbors.filter($n => $n && !$n.data('region')));
  }
}

function getCell(rowIndex, colIndex) {
  return $grid.find(`tr:eq(${rowIndex})`).find(`td:eq(${colIndex})`);
}

function getRandomColor(index) {
  return COLOR_PALETTE[index % COLOR_PALETTE.length];
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 2px dotted grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected-left { border-left: 2px solid red; }
.selected-right { border-right: 2px solid red; }
.selected-top { border-top: 2px solid red; }
.selected-bottom { border-bottom: 2px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="grid"></table>
```

Comment: The floodfill needs the "B" cells completely surrounded by borders without sharing any with the "A" region, alternatively make sure the "A" and "B" regions are sufficiently isolated by borders. Perhaps you can make two borders and collapse them?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up initializing the outer borders so that the entire grid begins as a single region.

```js
const COLOR_PALETTE = ['#FDD', '#DFD', '#DDF', '#FFD', '#DBF', '#BFD', '#FDB', '#BDF'];
const CLICK_THRESHOLD = 5;
const SAMPLE_DATA = [
  ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
  ['C', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
  ['C', 'D', 'B', 'B'],
  ['C', 'D', 'D', 'D']
];

(function($) {
  $.fn.fromMatrix = function(matrix) {
    return this
      .empty()
      .append($('<tbody>')
        .append(matrix.map((row, rowIndex) => $('<tr>')
          .append(row.map((val, colIndex) => $('<td>')
            .text(val))))));
  }
})(jQuery);

$('.grid').each(function() {
  const $grid = $(this).fromMatrix(SAMPLE_DATA);
  initializeBorders($grid);
});

$(document).on('click', '.grid td', onBorderClick);

function initializeBorders($table) {
    $table.find('tr').each(function(rowIndex, tr) {
    $(tr).find('td').each(function(colIndex, td) {
      const $cell = $(td).data('coords', [rowIndex, colIndex]);
      const neighbors = getNeighbors($table, rowIndex, colIndex);
      if (!neighbors.left.length) $cell.addClass('selected-left');
      if (!neighbors.right.length) $cell.addClass('selected-right');
      if (!neighbors.top.length) $cell.addClass('selected-top');
      if (!neighbors.bottom.length) $cell.addClass('selected-bottom');
    });
  });
}

function onBorderClick(event) {
  const $cell = $(this);
  const $table = $cell.closest('table');
  const { top, left, width, height } = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - left, y = event.clientY - top;
  toggleBorder($cell, x, y, width, height);
  distinguishRegions($table);
}

function getNeighbors($table, rowIndex, colIndex) {
  return {
    top:  getCell($table, rowIndex - 1, colIndex),
    right: getCell($table, rowIndex, colIndex + 1),
    bottom: getCell($table, rowIndex + 1, colIndex),
    left: getCell($table, rowIndex, colIndex - 1)
  };
}

function toggleBorder($cell, x, y, width, height) {
  if (x < CLICK_THRESHOLD) toggleLeft($cell);
  else if (x > width - CLICK_THRESHOLD) toggleRight($cell);
  else if (y < CLICK_THRESHOLD) toggleTop($cell);
  else if (y > height - CLICK_THRESHOLD) toggleBottom($cell);
}

function toggleLeft($cell) {
  $cell.toggleClass('selected-left');
  $cell.prev().toggleClass('selected-right');
}

function toggleRight($cell) {
  $cell.toggleClass('selected-right');
  $cell.next().toggleClass('selected-left');
}

function toggleTop($cell) {
  $cell.toggleClass('selected-top');
  $cell.parent().prev().children().eq($cell.index()).toggleClass('selected-bottom');
}

function toggleBottom($cell) {
  $cell.toggleClass('selected-bottom');
  $cell.parent().next().children().eq($cell.index()).toggleClass('selected-top');
}

function distinguishRegions($table) {
  const $cells = $table.find('td');
  // Clear previous regions
  $cells.css('background-color', '').removeData('region').removeAttr('data-region');
  let regionId = 0;
  $cells.each(function() {
    const $cell = $(this);
    if (!$cell.data('region')) {
      regionId++;
      floodFill($table, $cell, regionId);
    }
  });
}

function floodFill($table, $cell, regionId) {
  const queue = [$cell];
  while (queue.length > 0) {
    const $current = queue.shift();
    if ($current.length === 0 || $current.data('region')) continue;

    $current.data('region', regionId)
      .attr('data-region', regionId)
      .css('background-color', getColorByRegion(regionId - 1));

    const [rowIndex, colIndex] = $current.data('coords');
    const neighbors = getNeighbors($table, rowIndex, colIndex);
    const adjacencies = [
      !$current.hasClass('selected-top') && neighbors.top,
      !$current.hasClass('selected-bottom') && neighbors.bottom,
      !$current.hasClass('selected-left') && neighbors.left,
      !$current.hasClass('selected-right') && neighbors.right,
    ];

    queue.push(...adjacencies.filter($n => $n && !$n.data('region')));
  }
}

function getCell($table, rowIndex, colIndex) {
  const $rows = $table.find('tr');
  if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex >= $rows.length) return $();
  const $cells = $rows.eq(rowIndex).find('td');
  if (colIndex < 0 || colIndex >= $cells.length) return $();
  return $cells.eq(colIndex);
}

function getColorByRegion(regionIndex) {
  return COLOR_PALETTE[regionIndex % COLOR_PALETTE.length];
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 2px dotted grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected-left { border-left: 2px solid black; }
.selected-right { border-right: 2px solid black; }
.selected-top { border-top: 2px solid black; }
.selected-bottom { border-bottom: 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="grid"></table>
<table class="grid"></table>
<table class="grid"></table>
```